# "WannaCry" on Linux systems: How do you protect yourself?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, samba

According to [a rapid7 article](https://community.rapid7.com/community/infosec/blog/2017/05/25/patching-cve-2017-7494-in-samba-it-s-the-circle-of-life) there are some vulnerable [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) versions allowing a remote code execution on Linux systems:

> While the **WannaCry** ransomworm impacted Windows systems and was easily identifiable, with clear remediation steps, the **Samba** vulnerability will impact Linux and Unix systems and could present significant technical obstacles to obtaining or deploying appropriate remediations.

[CVE-2017-7494](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2017-7494.html)

> All versions of Samba from 3.5.0 onwards are vulnerable to a remote
> code execution vulnerability, allowing a malicious client to upload a
> shared library to a writable share, and then cause the server to load
> and execute it.

Possible attack scenario:

Starting from the two factors:

- The Samba vulnerability [isn't fixed](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/samba) yet on some Linux distributions.
- There is a non-patched local privilege escalation vulnerability on some Linux kernel versions (for example, CVE-2017-7308 on the 4.8.0-41-generic Ubuntu kernel).

An attacker can access a Linux machine and elevate privileges using a local exploit vulnerability to gain the root access and installing a possible future ramsomware, similar to this mock up  [WannaCry ransomware for Linux](https://github.com/zrools/WannaCry_for_Linux).

**Update**

A newest article ["Warning! Hackers Started Using "SambaCry Flaw" to Hack Linux Systems"](http://thehackernews.com/2017/06/linux-samba-vulnerability.html) demonstrate how to use the Sambacry flaw to infecte a linux machine.

> The prediction came out to be quite accurate, as honeypots set up by the team of researchers from [Kaspersky Lab](https://securelist.com/78674/sambacry-is-coming/) have captured a malware campaign that is exploiting SambaCry vulnerability to infect Linux computers with cryptocurrency mining software.
>
> Another security researcher, Omri Ben Bassat‏, independently discovered the same campaign and named it **"EternalMiner"** .
>
> According to the researchers, an unknown group of hackers has started hijacking Linux PCs just a week after the Samba flaw was disclosed publicly and installing an upgraded version of "CPUminer," a cryptocurrency mining software that mines "Monero" digital currency.
>
> After compromising the vulnerable machines using SambaCry vulnerability, attackers execute two payloads on the targeted systems:
>
> INAebsGB.so — A reverse-shell that provides remote access to the attackers.
>
> cblRWuoCc.so — A backdoor that includes cryptocurrency mining utilities – CPUminer.

TrendLab report posted on July 18, 2017: [Linux Users Urged to Update as a New Threat Exploits SambaCry](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/linux-users-urged-update-new-threat-exploits-sambacry/)

How do I secure a Linux system to prevent being attacked?

Comment: WannaCry is Windows malware. A unix virus could be written exploiting this unrelated problem with this unrelated implementation of the same protocol, but this has nothing to do with the windows malware. This link you give to WannaCry for Linux is a hoax, from skimming the source it looks like the output from some graphical "make your own gui"-software, without any actual program but a GUI which does nothing.

Comment: @GAD3R He is not being explicit. While I am not able to read chinese, a cursory inspection of the code seems to indicate your github link only displays an image.

Comment: @GAD3R Hence the comment "a GUI which does nothing" ; I originally myself thought he was talking about the CVE and just trolling until browsing the code.

Comment: @GAD3R using my iPhone with  Google Translate / camera mode the comments in Chinese say indeed the source is not complete. I would advise reworking the question around the CVE, deleting the github link and not about ransomware that still does not exist; or if you still want to work around that idea, making it explicit the github link is just a mock up of that idea

Comment: @GAD3R Yeah, if someone can access my system remotely with high privileges, it's much less of a pain to just use native Linux utilities to encrypt my hard drive, and write a QT GUI like that in the hoax. All the actual features (i.e. spreading) of WannaCry depend on Windows exploits. Mentioning "WannaCry" is click-baiting, pure and simple.

Comment: @Nobody To be fair enough, I believe the OP is in good faith and not aware of it being just a GUI;  we are not Chinese natives to read the comments and as he himself says, he is not very versed into reading source code; IMO the parallels between the two vulnerabilities, giving the timings are also appropriate. Give it some slack. Nonetheless, the implications of the CVE itself are worrisome.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Neither do I think OP was aware of it, but that doesn't make it better. I'm not judging, just thinking question should be overhauled. Vulnerabilities of this type are common enough that there is no good reason to relate those specific two to each other like this.

Comment: IMO I would not recommend closing the question, if someone has a different idea, go ahead. I have reworked the question text for it not to mention a ransomware that has not yet been made. The workaround that I mention was at least useful in a legacy system we still have.

Comment: Is not running (or even installing) Samba a sufficient defense?

Comment: Added again a couple of very relevant tidbits, and a detection script. Not everything is good news.

Comment: Added yet more links.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a windows topic.

Comment: How do you figure, @nwildner? The [CVE link](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2017-7494.html) on Samba's website explicitly says "All versions of Samba from 3.5.0 onwards"

Comment: Yeah. But that is not "WannaCry( CVE-2017-0144 )". Seems that the title is somehow "clickbait"... I can now see that closing could be a little drastic(sorry about voting wrong), but calling "SambaCry" a ransomware is at least misleading...

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This Samba new vulnerability is already being called "Sambacry", while the exploit itself mentions "Eternal Red Samba", announced in twitter (sensationally) as:

> Samba bug, the metasploit one-liner to trigger is just:
>   simple.create_pipe("/path/to/target.so")

Potentially affected Samba versions are from Samba 3.5.0 to 4.5.4/4.5.10/4.4.14.

If your Samba installation meets the configurations described bellow, the fix/upgrade should be done ASAP as there are already [exploits](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/42060/), other [exploit in python](https://github.com/opsxcq/exploit-CVE-2017-7494) and
[metasploit](https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/142715/Samba-is_known_pipename-Arbitrary-Module-Load.html) modules out there.

More interestingly enough, there are already add-ons to a know honeypot from the [honeynet](http://honeynet.org) project, [dionaea](https://dionaea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) both to WannaCry and [SambaCry plug-ins](http://honeynet.org/node/1353).

Samba cry seems to be already being (ab)used to [install more crypto-miners](http://thehackernews.com/2017/06/linux-samba-vulnerability.html) "EternalMiner" or [double down as a malware dropper in the future](https://securelist.com/78674/sambacry-is-coming/).

> honeypots set up by the team of researchers from Kaspersky Lab have
>   captured a malware campaign that is exploiting SambaCry vulnerability
>   to infect Linux computers with cryptocurrency mining software. Another
>   security researcher, Omri Ben Bassat‏, independently [discovered](https://twitter.com/omri9741/status/872731228859809793) the
>   same campaign and named it "EternalMiner."

The advised workaround for systems with Samba installed (which also is present in the CVE notice) before updating it, is adding to `smb.conf`:

```
nt pipe support = no
```

(and restarting the Samba service)

This is supposed to disable a setting that turns on/off the ability to make anonymous connections to the windows IPC named pipes service.  From `man samba`:

> This global option is used by developers to allow or disallow Windows
>   NT/2000/XP clients the ability to make connections to NT-specific SMB
>   IPC$ pipes. As a user, you should never need to override the default.

However from our internal experience, it seems the fix is not compatible with older? Windows versions ( at least some? Windows 7 clients seem to not work with the `nt pipe support = no`), and as such the remediation route can go in extreme cases into installing or even compiling Samba.

More specifically, this fix  disable shares listing from Windows clients, and if applied they have to manually specify the full path of the share to be able to use it.

Other known workaround is to make sure Samba shares are mounted with the `noexec` option. This will prevent the execution of binaries residing on the mounted filesystem.

The official security source code patch is [here](https://download.samba.org/pub/samba/patches/security/samba-4.6.3-4.5.9-4.4.13-CVE-2017-7494.patch) from the [samba.org security page](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/security.html).

Debian already pushed yesterday (24/5) an update out the door, and the corresponding security notice [DSA-3860-1 samba](https://www.debian.org/security/2017/dsa-3860)

To verify in if the vulnerability is corrected in Centos/RHEL/Fedora and derivates, do:

```
#rpm -q –changelog samba | grep -i CVE
– resolves: #1450782 – Fix CVE-2017-7494
– resolves: #1405356 – CVE-2016-2125 CVE-2016-2126
– related: #1322687 – Update CVE patchset
```

There is now an `nmap` detection script :[`samba-vuln-cve-2017-7494.nse`](https://gist.github.com/wongwaituck/62c863ba7aa28a2d22d0fe9cbe14a18b)  for detecting Samba versions, or a much better `nmap` script that checks if the service is vulnerable at http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2017/q2/att-110/samba-vuln-cve-2017-7494.nse , copy it to `/usr/share/nmap/scripts` and then update the `nmap` database , or run it as follows:

```
nmap --script /path/to/samba-vuln-cve-2017-7494.nse -p 445 <target>
```

About long term measures to protect the SAMBA service:  The SMB protocol should never be offered directly to the Internet at large.

It goes also without saying that SMB has always been a convoluted protocol, and that these kind of services ought to be firewalled and restricted to the internal networks [to which they are being served].

When remote access is needed, either to home or specially to corporate networks, those accesses should be better done using VPN technology.

As usual, on this situations the Unix principle of only installing and activating the minimum services required does pay off.

Taken from the exploit itself:

> Eternal Red Samba Exploit -- CVE-2017-7494.
>           Causes vulnerable Samba server to load a shared library in root context.
>           Credentials are not required if the server has a guest account.
>           For remote exploit you must have write permissions to at least one share.
>           Eternal Red will scan the Samba server for shares it can write to.
>           It will also determine the fullpath of the remote share.
>
> ```
>     For local exploit provide the full path to your shared library to load.  
>
>     Your shared library should look something like this
>
>     extern bool change_to_root_user(void);
>     int samba_init_module(void)
>     {
>         change_to_root_user();
>         /* Do what thou wilt */
>     }
> ```

It is also known systems with SELinux enabled are not vulnerable to the exploit.

See [7-Year-Old Samba Flaw Lets Hackers Access Thousands of Linux PCs Remotely](http://thehackernews.com/2017/05/samba-rce-exploit.html)

> According to the Shodan computer search engine, more than 485,000
>   Samba-enabled computers exposed port 445 on the Internet, and
>   according to researchers at Rapid7, more than 104,000 internet-exposed
>   endpoints appeared to be running vulnerable versions of Samba, out of
>   which 92,000 are running unsupported versions of Samba.
>
> Since Samba is
>   the SMB protocol implemented on Linux and UNIX systems, so some
>   experts are saying it is "Linux version of EternalBlue," used by the
>   WannaCry ransomware.
>
> ...or should I say SambaCry?
>
> Keeping in mind the
>   number of vulnerable systems and ease of exploiting this
>   vulnerability, the Samba flaw could be exploited at large scale with
>   wormable capabilities.
>
> Home networks with network-attached storage
>   (NAS) devices [that also run Linux] could also be vulnerable to this flaw.

See also [A wormable code-execution bug has lurked in Samba for 7 years. Patch now!](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/05/a-wormable-code-execution-bug-has-lurked-in-samba-for-7-years-patch-now/)

> The seven-year-old flaw, indexed as CVE-2017-7494, can be reliably
>   exploited with just one line of code to execute malicious code, as
>   long as a few conditions are met. Those requirements include
>   vulnerable computers that:
>
> (a) make file- and printer-sharing port 445
>   reachable on the Internet,
>   (b) configure shared files to have write
>   privileges, and
>   (c) use known or guessable server paths for those
>   files.
>
> When those conditions are satisfied, remote attackers can
>   upload any code of their choosing and cause the server to execute it,
>   possibly with unfettered root privileges, depending on the vulnerable
>   platform.
>
> Given the ease and reliability of exploits, this hole is worth
>   plugging as soon as possible. It's likely only a matter of time until
>   attackers begin actively targeting it.

Also [Rapid 7 - Patching CVE-2017-7494 in Samba: It’s the Circle of Life](https://community.rapid7.com/community/infosec/blog/2017/05/25/patching-cve-2017-7494-in-samba-it-s-the-circle-of-life)

And more [SambaCry: The Linux Sequel to WannaCry](https://f5.com/labs/articles/threat-intelligence/cyber-security/sambacry-the-linux-sequel-to-wannacry).

> Need-to-Know Facts
>
> CVE-2017-7494 has a CVSS Score of 7.5
>   (CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:H/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H)3.
>
> Threat Scope
>
> A shodan.io query of "port:445 !os:windows" shows approximately one
>   million non-Windows hosts that have tcp/445 open to the Internet, more
>   than half of which exist in the United Arab Emirates (36%) and the
>   U.S. (16%).   While many of these may be running patched versions,
>   have SELinux protections, or otherwise don't match the necessary
>   criteria for running the exploit, the possible attack surface for this
>   vulnerability is large.

P.S. The commit fix in the SAMBA github project appear to be commit [02a76d86db0cbe79fcaf1a500630e24d961fa149](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/commit/02a76d86db0cbe79fcaf1a500630e24d961fa149)

Comment: You are welcome. I would add that in my time zone, I acted on the Debian security notice yesterday around 9AM

Comment: Unlike in Windows though, Samba isn't on by default in most Linux distros right?

Comment: @raphael Indeed, but if I received a penny for every server I found with the full set of core DVDs installed...I have edited slightly the answer to address that idea.

Comment: As far as I can tell that nmap script just checks the version of samba, not if you're vulnerable. AFAICT, to exploit the vulnerability, one needs to be able to upload files to the server. So the vulnerability is nowhere as serious as the Eternalblue Windows one. If you allow uploading files over the internet without authentication, you have a problem whether samba is vulnerable or not.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, I have had not yet time to check the script

Comment: I'd still call the pun SambaCry misled: In the windows case, it is a malware with a known and dangerous payload in the wild- in the samba case, it is the vulnerability itself?

Comment: The linked commits do not look relevant to this bug.

Answer (score 21):

Most of us running Samba servers out there are probably running it inside LANs, behind firewalls and don't expose its ports directly to the outside world.

It would an awful practice if you did so, and inexcusable one when there are simple, effective and free (as in beer and as in speech) VPN solutions like OpenVPN around. SMB was not designed with open Internet in mind (heck, TCP/IP even came as an afterthought in that protocol) and should be treated as such. Additional suggestion is running firewall rules on the actual file sharing host that whitelist only local (and eventually VPN) network adresses on all SMB ports (`139/TCP`, `445/TCP`, `137/UDP` and `138/UDP`).

Also, if your use case allows, you should consider running Samba unprivileged (as, say, `samba` user who is not alias of `root`). I understand that it's not that easy to marry limitations of NT ACLs with POSIX ACLs with this setup but if it's possible to do so in your particular setup it's the way to go.

Finally, even with such a "lockdown" it's still advisable to apply a patch if you can (because there are NAS boxes out there where that might not be doable), and to test if your particular use case works with `nt pipe support` set to `no`.

Comment: “It's only accessible on the intranet” is probably what some of the admins in companies where WannaCry spread thought.