# How to mitigate the multiple vulnerability : remote code execution and local privilege escalation on FreeBSD 11?

Tags: security, freebsd, kde, vulnerability, pkg

By checking the state of installed package using the `pkg audit -F` tool on freeBSD 11 , I have found 4 vulnerability on the installed packages (installed through `pkg`) : `samba` ,`OpenEXR` , `kdelibs` and `ImageMagick` .

I have upgraded  `ImageMagick` and `samba` to the latest version ( +  following the [mitigation guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367148/153195) for samba : adding `nt pipe support = no` to `nsmb.conf`) .

```
#pkg search samba
p5-Samba-LDAP-0.05_2           Manage a Samba PDC with an LDAP Backend
p5-Samba-SIDhelper-0.0.0_3     Create SIDs based on G/UIDs
samba-nsupdate-9.8.6_1         nsupdate utility with GSS-TSIG support
samba42-4.2.14_1               Free SMB/CIFS and AD/DC server and client for Unix
samba43-4.3.13_2               Free SMB/CIFS and AD/DC server and client for Unix
samba44-4.4.13                 Free SMB/CIFS and AD/DC server and client for Unix
samba45-4.5.8                  Free SMB/CIFS and AD/DC server and client for Unix
samba46-4.6.2                  Free SMB/CIFS and AD/DC server and client for Unix
```

There is no upgrade available for `OpenEXR` and `kdelibs` , the latest version is already installed.

I am using the KDE4 on FreeBSD 11 , the `kdelibs` vulnerability affect Linux and Unix systems with the KDE4/KDE5 desktop environment.

How to mitigate the  multiple vulnerability : remote code execution and local privilege escalation on FreeBSD 11?

```
# pkg audit -F
vulnxml file up-to-date
ImageMagick7-7.0.3.7_1 is vulnerable:
ImageMagick -- multiple vulnerabilities
CVE: CVE-2017-9144
CVE: CVE-2017-9143
CVE: CVE-2017-9142
CVE: CVE-2017-9141
CVE: CVE-2017-8830
CVE: CVE-2017-8765
CVE: CVE-2017-8357
CVE: CVE-2017-8356
CVE: CVE-2017-8355
CVE: CVE-2017-8354
CVE: CVE-2017-8353
CVE: CVE-2017-8352
CVE: CVE-2017-8351
CVE: CVE-2017-8350
CVE: CVE-2017-8349
CVE: CVE-2017-8348
CVE: CVE-2017-8347
CVE: CVE-2017-8346
CVE: CVE-2017-8345
CVE: CVE-2017-8344
CVE: CVE-2017-8343
CVE: CVE-2017-7943
CVE: CVE-2017-7942
CVE: CVE-2017-7941
CVE: CVE-2017-7619
CVE: CVE-2017-7606
CVE: CVE-2017-7275
CVE: CVE-2017-6502
CVE: CVE-2017-6501
CVE: CVE-2017-6500
CVE: CVE-2017-6499
CVE: CVE-2017-6498
CVE: CVE-2017-6497
CVE: CVE-2017-5511
CVE: CVE-2017-5510
CVE: CVE-2017-5509
CVE: CVE-2017-5508
CVE: CVE-2017-5507
CVE: CVE-2017-5506
WWW: https://vuxml.FreeBSD.org/freebsd/50776801-4183-11e7-b291-b499baebfeaf.html

kdelibs-4.14.30_1 is vulnerable:
kauth: Local privilege escalation
CVE: CVE-2017-8422
WWW: https://vuxml.FreeBSD.org/freebsd/0baee383-356c-11e7-b9a9-50e549ebab6c.html

OpenEXR-2.2.0_7 is vulnerable:
OpenEXR -- multiple remote code execution and denial of service vulnerabilities
CVE: CVE-2017-9116
CVE: CVE-2017-9115
CVE: CVE-2017-9114
CVE: CVE-2017-9113
CVE: CVE-2017-9112
CVE: CVE-2017-9111
CVE: CVE-2017-9110
WWW: https://vuxml.FreeBSD.org/freebsd/803879e9-4195-11e7-9b08-080027ef73ec.html

samba46-4.6.2 is vulnerable:
samba -- remote code execution vulnerability
CVE: CVE-2017-7494
WWW: https://vuxml.FreeBSD.org/freebsd/6f4d96c0-4062-11e7-b291-b499baebfeaf.html

4 problem(s) in the installed packages found.
```

Comment: Thxs for the heads up, using 12 at home, will check it later on

Comment: a FreeBSD 12 update solved all bugs, except OpenEXR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **KDE bug** - [No mitigation](https://www.kde.org/info/security/advisory-20170510-1.txt). Update to `kauth >= 5.34` and `kdelibs >= 4.14.32` (when released) is the solution provided by KDE folks. Just wait for the updated port to have this problem fixed.
- **OpenEXR bugs** - [No mitigation](https://github.com/openexr/openexr/issues/232), and the devs are not showing any sign that they will fix this soon. Best guess here is to remove this package, if you don't really use it (neither is a dependency).